# Set background color in Bitmap Image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmap

I want to save my canvas to image. It works but background color is black. How I must add to change the color?

I use this code:

```
Size size = new Size(surface.Width, surface.Height);

surface.Measure(size);
surface.Arrange(new Rect(size));

// Create a render bitmap and push the surface to it
RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap =
    new RenderTargetBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96d, 96d,
                           PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
renderBitmap.Render(surface);

// Create a file stream for saving image
using (FileStream outStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
{
    BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
    // push the rendered bitmap to it
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));
    // save the data to the stream
    encoder.Save(outStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `PixelFormats.Default` or `PixelFormats.Bgra32` or `PixelFormats.Rgb24` instead of `PixelFormats.Pbgra32`.

The **P** stands for pre-multiplied - the assumption is that each channel is pre-multiplied by alpha.

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pixelformats.aspx)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Render throws an invalid format exception for any A format without a P.

Comment: @david.pfx ask a question with the details of your problem. Check the properties of the object you have (format, stride) to see what is different.

Comment: I don't have a question. I tried the answer exactly as given and the Render() works for Pbgra32 and not for any of the formats suggested. The accepted answer looks wrong to me.

Comment: @david.pfx your input is different, hence the differing results.

Comment: @david.pfx This answer is 8.5 years old and solved the problem at the time. Technologies change a lot in a single year let alone 8.5 years. I am not payed for answering questions here, I do it to help people that want to help themselves. In addition I no longer work with the relevant technologies. I suggest you ask a new question with all the relevant details. Thanks for the vote down btw!

Comment: The down vote is because the answer is of poor quality, it won't help other readers and you won't fix it. It's too short, and based on my testing it's either plain wrong or it only works for some unspecified subset of situations. I doubt that Microsoft is to blame. Improve the answer and I'll happily change my vote.

Comment: @david.pfx image files you load are usually RGB24, BGRA32, I have never seen a file with a pre-multiplied alpha channel. I have no idea why you insist on using one instead of trying to create an image differently. WPF as it was in 2012 was for Windows only on .NET Framework 3.5 and back then this worked - I used this myself. Now MS uses a new tech for Windows 8+ that did not exist then and .NET5+ is not even based on earlier .NET Frameworks, but more on .NET Core that did not exist then. This answer is for .NET 3.5 WPF, you are welcome to add an update with the new class/function names.

Answer (score 5):

**Try this**

```
Size size = new Size(surface.Width, surface.Height);

surface.Measure(size);
surface.Arrange(new Rect(size));

// Create a render bitmap and push the surface to it
RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap =
    new RenderTargetBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96d, 96d,
                           PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
{
    VisualBrush visualBrush = new VisualBrush(surface);
    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(visualBrush, null, 
      new Rect(new Point(), new Size(size.Width, size.Height)));
}

renderBitmap.Render(drawingVisual);

// Create a file stream for saving image
using (FileStream outStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
{
    BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
    // push the rendered bitmap to it
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));
    // save the data to the stream
    encoder.Save(outStream);
}
```