# How to change color of transparent image?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have some transparent images which are in black and white.I want to change the color of these transparent images using color picker. How can i do that.

```
  <Image  x:Name="img" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="Fill"  Width="50" Height="50"  Margin="148,263,0,375"   >
        </Image>
      <c4fToolkit:ColorPicker x:Name="picker" Height="200" 
             Width="200" ColorChanged="picker_ColorChanged"  Margin="270,283,10,245" Opacity="0.5" />
```

And the .cs code is

```
private void picker_ColorChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Media.Color color)
{
    tattoo.Source = new SolidColorBrush(color);
}
```

Comment: Is converting the raster images to vector paths an option?

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the image inside a stackpanel or grid and set its background

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Background="Aqua" Height="100" Width="100" Grid.Row="0">
    <Image Name="img" Source="Assets/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" Height="100" Width="100"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: sorry i am not able to understand what you trying to convey

Comment: you cant change the the background color of image. thats why keep the transparent image inside a stackpanel and change its background color. because image is transparent it will reflect the color you set.

Comment: you can change the stackpannel background color from CS code as well

Comment: of course. Just set the stackpanel name and use it from code behind.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346949/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-stackpanel-programmatically-in-window

Comment: appreciate your effort @Nishi but still the color of image not changing..it changes the background of grid and because of that i also not able to see the transparent image which i set,

Comment: can you please attach a snapshot of what you are getting. and the code snippet you tried.

Comment: sorry that i can't becz of some reasons, but from your code it changes the background color of grid and due to this my image is also not visible.

Comment: have attached a screenshot for what I am getting? is it what you too are expecting?

Comment: no thats not what i expecting this changes the background of the image. i want to change the color of my transparent image which are in black and white.i am using a color picker to change it..for example my transparent image color is black and if i chose the color red from the picker the color of my image also changes from black to red. that what i want

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816582/set-background-color-in-bitmap-image

Comment: no @nishi still the same this is not what i want..its like my question is very complicated..:p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80849/discussion-between-nishi-and-ritu-tyagi).

Comment: @RituTyagi: The simplest way is just use a border control and put your image inside it. now you will be able to change the colour of your image.